# Sending mail in Meteor run slowly

Tags: meteor

I use this code to send emails on command by client, emails are sent fine but the thing is this method run very slow. Am I missing something?

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (/*...*/) {
    // ...
    Email.send({
      // ...
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It's to be expected that it runs slow, because it uses SMTP to send the email. Most times it will actually try to contact the remote email server directly and send the email to it. This all takes some time, hence the slow performance.

Comment: add this.unblock(); beffore emai.send() does it help?